# Cors errors when requesting from azure web storage to jira with excel Add-in

Tags: excel, cors, axios, jira

I've worked on add-in to Excel written in React that gets data from my company Jira and makes specific worksheet out of that data. When i was developing this i've made a simple Express proxy and it worked like a charm.

I've recently deployed it to Azure App service and the add-in loads in excel but it is not allowed to make requests to Jira and i get CORS error:

[image: CORS error].

Is there some workaround for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add it to Whitelist and enable incoming request:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-the-whitelist-381255821.html